# How can I use spline() with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

I would like to fit my data using spline(y~x) but all of the examples  that I can find use a spline with smoothing,  e.g. lm(y~ns(x), df=_).

I want to use `spline()` specifically because I am using this to do the analysis represented by the plot that I am making.

Is there a simple way to use spline() in ggplot?

I have considered the hackish approach of fitting a line using

```
geom_smooth(aes(x=(spline(y~x)$x, y=spline(y~x)$y))
```

but I would prefer not to have to resort to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))
ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=data.frame(spline(d, n=n*10)))
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for; nice and simple. thanks

Comment: what if I want to draw two lines, e.g. for the `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` in `d<-data.frame(x1=1:n, y1=rnorm(n), x2=1:n+0.5, y2=runif(10))`? I am having trouble with the line `geom_line(aes(x1,y1), data=data.frame(spline(x1,y1)))`

Comment: the answer to the above is: `geom_line(aes(d$x1,d$y1), data=data.frame(spline(x1,y1)))`, although I am not sure why...

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, with `ggformula` https://rdrr.io/cran/ggformula/man/geom_spline.html, you can call `ggformula::stat_spline()` directly within `ggplot()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggformula)

n<-1000
d <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))
ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+
  # geom_point()+
  stat_spline()
```

[image]

Note: OP asked specifically about using `spline()`. `stat_spline() {ggformula}` calls `smooth.spline() {stats}`, which might not be exactly the same implementation as `spline() {stats}` but think it may still be a useful answer here for others.